# How to pass data like an anonymous object from Jquery datatable in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a Jquery datatable in my ASP.NET MVC view. The columns are like this :

```
"columns": [
                        { "data": "Vote", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "Answer1", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "View", "autoWidth": true },
                        {
                            "data": "Title", "autoWidth": true,
                            'render': function (Title)
                            {
                                //return '<a href=' + Title + '>' + Title + '</a>';
                                return '<a href=/Questions/GoForAnswer/?idForAnswer='+ 2+'&title=dfg&question=dfg&view=59&date=08%2F10%2F2016%2023%3A39%3A17&answerNumber=13&vote=113>' + Title + '</a>';
                            }
                        }
                ]
```

Here in title column, I have hard coded the url that returns bunch of objects.But these objects are dynamic. I want to send these into the query string. Like I used to send them like this :

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "GoForAnswer", new { idForAnswer = item.ID, title = item.Title, question = item.Question, view = item.View, date = item.Date, answerNumber = item.Answer1, vote = item.Vote })
```

How can I send the objects from my Jquery function.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can make a model with the same names as your object example:

```
public class PeopleObject
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public int age     {get;set;}
}
```

then all you have to do is make you jquery object with the same names example:

```
var uniqueObjectName = [{name:'example1',age:20},{name:'example2',age:30}];
```

then after that you send the jquery object to you controller with ajax and pass the object as a variable example of ajax:

```
var uniqueObjectName = [{name:'example1',age:20},{name:'example2',age:30}];        // #1
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: uniqueObjectName , // #2
        url: '/Home/SubmitMyData',
        //contentType: 'application/json', #3
        //dataType: 'json', #2
        success: alert('Youhou'),
        error: alert('not good')
    });
```

in you controller you receive the object like :

```
public ActionResult Index(PeopleObject uniqueObjectName )
{
    return View();
}
```

notice the controller parameter name and the jquery variable name is the same...
The controller will automatically map the object to the model

Comment: But, I don't know the exact name,example as your solution. I can't hard code like this. I need to pass an anonymous object as we pass in html.actionlink()

new {name where title =title,age where title = title}
can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Better construct your query in a different way, instead of passing the `url` directly to `$.ajax`, modify it to meet your needs.
So, essentially you store the razor generated URL, from `@Html.RouteUrl` method, in a JavaScript variable. Then you append the query string.

Because, in this case, the query string contains dynamic values, meaning some might not be listed in every request you need to have them listed in a placeholder variable, and replace values accordingly.

After you done with that, you just append the query string to the base URL and provide it to `$.ajax`.

Take a look at the following example (I have included a fiddle link to see it in action). I store the `@Route.Url` generated URL in the `url` variable. I also have declared all the keys of the model in `keys` table, as well as defined a `placeholder` string to replace values accordingly.

In `fixPlaceholder` method I just replace all the `{key}=${placeholder}` occurrences with the value of my `data` object (from there you get your dynamic values) or empty (if the value is not set for that particular property).

Finally, I append the `placeholder` to the `url` and pass it to `$.ajax`. Binding will do its magic on the `ASP.NET MVC` side, so do not worry about that, just declare your controller's action normally, expecting a complex object, like in this example:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetModelAction(SampleViewModel model) {
    // Your code here...
}
```

For your client code you can have something like this:

```
function fixPlaceholder (keys, data, placeholder) {
    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        placeholder = placeholder.replace(keys[i] + "=${PLACEHOLDER}", keys[i] + "=" + (data[keys[i]] || ""));
    }

    return placeholder;
}

$(function(){
    $("button").on("click", function () {
        var keys = ["Title", "Question", "AnswerNumber", "View", "Date", "Vote"];

        var data = {Title:"Myitle", Question:"MyQuestion", Vote:"10"};

        var placeholder = "?Title=${PLACEHOLDER}&Question=${PLACEHOLDER}&AnswerNumber=${PLACEHOLDER}&View=${PLACEHOLDER}&Date=${PLACEHOLDER}&Vote=${PLACEHOLDER}";

        var url = '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="GetModelAsJson", controller="Home"})';

        placeholder = fixPlaceholder(keys, data, placeholder);

        url = url + placeholder;

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        }).then(function(resp) {
                console.log("Response");
                console.log(resp);
        });
    });
```

Here is a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tUpJ8G), check it and try to work your way based on that. Hope this helps.

**Note**

Because you are using values that might not be set in the model in every request, meaning they might be null, you need to pay attention to your back-end model. That said, if you have any properties with types like `int`, `DateTime`, etc. you might need to mark them as nullable, in order to avoid hairy situations. Like the model below.

```
using System;
namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class SampleViewModel
    {

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Question { get; set; }

        public int? AnswerNumber { get; set; }

        public string View { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

        public string Vote { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code and information.
var data contains static fields here. Such as : Title:"Myitle", Question:"MyQuestion". I need to generate a query here. Like: Title:"Myitle", Question : select question where title = MyTitle. Can I do that?